# Which one is correct: "Viens là" or “Viens-là”?

Tags: pronoms, verbes, adverbes, trait-d-union

I have seen this phrase written with and without a hyphen.  Why is that?  In which instances is which one right?
What verb does "viens" come from anyway?

Comment: I wonder: Is not this question, and others like it, actually off-topic? For what does this user really ask? What _viens_ means. Don't we have dictionaries for this kind of questions? Type _viens_ into any type of search box, and you will instantly know what it means, and where it ultimately comes from. So let's not turn this site into a dictionary!

Comment: @indoxica: my LAROUSSE actually doesn't have "viens" or "viens-là" in it.  I do check before asking so don't pre-judge.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Because _viens_ is and inflected form of the verb _venir_. French is an inflected language, you know. And "words" like _viens_ are therefore not proper words; _venir_ is. Had you followed my advice and typed _viens_ into any search box, you would have seen how right I was.

Comment: @verve You can use [http://fr.wiktionary.org/](http://fr.wiktionary.org/) to look up inflected forms. It will always give you the links to the 'dictionary' form. They also provide excellent conjugation tables, e.g. [venir](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Conjugaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais/venir).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Viens* is the 2nd person singular imperative present of the verb *venir*: *to come*.

I would not put a hyphen in “Viens là”, I can't see any reason to do so. *Viens* et *là* are two well separated words, as in “Come here”.

Comment: 2nd person singular imperative?  Confusing.  The hyphen is interesting!  I kept seeing it online and I was like "why are people typing it like that" ?

Comment: See nothing confusing in this answer.

Comment: If you only write "Viens là", then you do not use a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Although the rules governing the French hyphenation may be confusing sometimes there is not **viens-là.** It is **viens là** sans hyphen.

http://www.francparler-oif.org/grac-a1a2/contenu-generique/viens-la-a-cote-de-moi-la-ici-la-bas/

You can learn more for the french imperative here

https://www.talkinfrench.com/learning-french-imperative-imperatif/

The verb and the pronoun are linked together with a hyphen in the affirmative imperative.

> Excusez-moi. (Excuse me.) Aide-nous. (Help us.)

There are cases when both direct and indirect object pronouns are present. During these scenarios, the DIRECT OBJECT PRONOUNS always come BEFORE the INDIRECT OBJECT PRONOUNS.

> Donnez-la-nous! (Give it to us!) Prête-les moi! (Lend them to me!)

But là is but an adverb like here, there and the like. No need for hyphens. There are indeed some webpages using viens-là but this is not correct french. It is just (I guess) for help the users to memorize the link and for https convenience:-)!

Answer (score -3):

As a french, the "là" comes with an hyphen in "Viens-là" or when it follows a verb  or a noun.

Comment: Let's see if I understood well: because "là" is French, it comes with a hyphen when following a verb or a noun? How strange that the French nature of a word means it has a hyphen coming along with it. Probably the baguette under its arm and sticking out behind it, I suppose...